# Angular controller getting called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I've seen this issue asked however, I'm a little stumped with mine. Solutions state to remove one of the controllers.  So when I remove the ng-controller=sigSearchResults from the body tag, my results do not get populated in the ng-grid="gridOptions" .  How do rectify this?

```
var sig = angular.module('sig', ['ngRoute']);

    sig.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/search/:sig', {
             template : ' ',
             controller : 'sigSearchResults'
        }).when('/', {
             template : ' ',
             controller : 'sigSearchResults'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/'
        });
    } ]);

sig.controller('sigSearchResults', function($scope,$log,$http,$q,$routeParams, $window) {
    console.log($routeParams);
    //code that populates ng-grid to gridOptions element.
});


<html ng-app="sig">    
<body ng-controller="sigSearchResults">
<div class="contentContainer">

    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- This is the template for the result -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="sig-search-result-id" >

    <div ng-show="loading" style='clear:both; text-align: center;'>Loading report...<img src="../media/images/Wait3.gif"></div>


    <div ng-show="!loading" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, remove the `ng-controller="sigSearchResults"` from your `<body>` tag as you're using the `$routeProvider` to configure routing and views and it doesn't look like your controller should be running at the top level.

Looks like all you're missing is the `tempateUrl` in your route configuration, ie

```
when('/', {
     templateUrl: 'sig-search-result-id',
     controller: 'sigSearchResults'
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but with template vs templateURL. Works now :).